# Order rows and display order number

Tags: mysql

I already have a query which results like this

```
+-----------+------------+---------------+--------+
| DetailsNo |  SaleDate  | Country       | Value  |
+-----------+------------+---------------+--------+
|       277 | 2012-02-10 | PHI           |     42 |
|       279 | 2012-02-10 | PHI           |     10 |
|       280 | 2012-02-10 | USA           |     30 |
|       281 | 2012-02-10 | USA           |     25 |
|       282 | 2012-02-10 | FRA           |     65 |
|       283 | 2012-02-10 | FRA           |     36 |
|       284 | 2012-02-10 | GER           |     47 |
+-----------+------------+---------------+--------+
```

What i need is to add another column and display a sort of order number like the following :

```
+-----------+------------+---------------+--------+--------+
| DetailsNo |  SaleDate  | Country       | Value  | Order  |
+-----------+------------+---------------+--------+--------+
|       277 | 2012-02-10 | PHI           |     42 |      1 |
|       279 | 2012-02-10 | PHI           |     10 |      2 |
|       280 | 2012-02-10 | USA           |     30 |      1 |
|       281 | 2012-02-10 | USA           |     25 |      2 |
|       282 | 2012-02-10 | FRA           |     65 |      1 |
|       283 | 2012-02-10 | FRA           |     36 |      2 |
|       284 | 2012-02-10 | GER           |     47 |      1 |
+-----------+------------+---------------+--------+--------+
```

Is this possible?

Comment: What is your existing code? What have you tried and what were the problems?

Comment: In practice, it's highly unlikely that you'd want to store this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use variables for this:

```
SELECT DetailsNo, SaleDate, Country, Value,
       @rn := IF(@c = Country, @rn + 1,
                 IF(@c := Country, 1, 1)) AS 'Order'
FROM mytable
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0, @c := '') AS vars
ORDER BY Country, DetailsNo
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0497e/3)

Comment: DO NOT CALL THE COLUMN 'ORDER'.

Comment: @Strawberry there is no reason to shout no matter what the issue is.

Comment: I'm not shouting. I'm emphasising every word ;-)

Comment: Cross Join is new to me. It's working now but I need to study how this join works. Thanks! :D